# What exactly is a k-cell?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I've been reading over Rudin's Mathematical Analysis (Ch. 2 Topology), and it seems to just suddenly talk about k-cells out of nowhere. More specifically, they state this theorem:

> Every k-cell is compact.

without giving a clear definition of what a k-cell is. So I'm wondering, what exactly is a k-cell? Is is simply a higher-dimension set? For instance, for theorems involving some set $E \subseteq X$, is $E$ just a "k-cell in $\mathbb{R}^1$"? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look in the index? "Cell" is defined on page 31. (In the 3rd edition, anyway.)